# Compile Error "Expected: =" when calling another procedure

Tags: vba

I try to call a procedure giving to arguments, it throws a compile error stating "Expected: =".

```
...

Dim isWorkaround As Boolean
isWorkaround = False
If Check101.Value = True Then
     isWorkaround = True
End If

...

'Procedure I try to call
ElseIf Combo_Report_Selection = "Adjusted Report" And Combo_someOther= "Other" Then
   Call_01_Adj_Report(div, isWorkaround)
ElseIf Combo_Report_Selection = "Upload Log" Then
   Call_03_Upload_Log
ElseIf Combo_Report_Selection = "Gather Summary" Then
   Call_04_Adj_Summary
End If

Combo_Report_Selection.Value = Null
Combo_Statement.Value = Null

End Sub
__________________________________________

Private Sub Call_01_Adj_Report(ByRef calldiv As Long, ByRef isWorkaround As Boolean)

...

End Sub
__________________________________________
```

It fails when I insert the call " Call_01_Adj_Report(div, isWorkaround)".
It works when giving only one Parameter, but not for two. But in my understanding, the procedure call with arguments syntax is right. What might be the problem?

Comment: See [this is confusing, why not just always use parentheses?](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/vba/1179/procedure-calls/3818/this-is-confusing-why-not-just-always-use-parentheses#t=201705051655467680223) to understand why you need to remove the parentheses there. Your procedure call syntax is *not* right.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon link is now broken as Stackoverflow has shutdown "documentation"

Comment: @Trashman that content can also be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45747922/1188513) on SO, and RIP Tutorial has the original SO Doc article [here](https://riptutorial.com/vba/example/3818/this-is-confusing--why-not-just-always-use-parentheses-).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your procedure call syntax is *not* right.

This: `Call_01_Adj_Report(div, isWorkaround)`

Needs to be: `Call_01_Adj_Report div, isWorkaround`

Or, with the obsolete *explicit call* syntax: `Call Call_01_Adj_Report(div, isWorkaround)`

I normally dislike *explicit call* syntax quite much, but here I like how it highlights how weird the procedure name is. Avoid underscores in public members (should be `PascalCase`), and start procedure names with a verb, e.g. `CreateAdjustmentsReport`:

```
CreateAdjustmentsReport div, isWorkaround
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to maintain parenthesis for calling a `sub`:

use `Call` keyword

```
Call Call_01_Adj_Report(div, isWorkaround)
```

Similarly if you declare a function that returns value (not sub), you can call the function with parenthesis without using "Call"

**example:**

```
Public Function func(ByVal variable As Integer)
  variable = variable + 100
End Function

Public Sub test()
    func (10)
End Sub
```