# Excel VBA SQL ADODB Not Inserting Row Into Worksheet (NO ERRORS)

Tags: sql, excel, vba

My insert statement has been working, but randomly stops inserting, until I go into the workbook I'm inserting into and manually change something and save.

The db workbook currently has around 15,000 rows that have been previously inserted, but now when I run the macro, it doesn't insert anything and there are no errors. I've stepped through the code, and every line executes normally.

I need help figuring out why nothing is being inserted, when it worked before.

```
Sub Insert
    Dim con As ADODB.Connection
    Dim InsertSQL As String

    InsertSQL = "INSERT INTO [Sheet1$] ([FIELD1],[FIELD2],[FIELD3],[FIELD4],[FIELD5]) VALUES( 1234567895,9350.00,#9/12/2019#,'username',#9/12/2019 10:05 AM#)"
    Set con = New ADODB.Connection
    con.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & dbpath & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=0""; Mode=ReadWrite;"
    con.Execute InsertSQL
    con.Close
End Sub
```

Edit:
I've set default values in the first 8 rows of my db workbook so as not to cause any limitations in data types as specified in:

> This is an issue with the Jet OLEDB provider. It looks at the first 8
>   rows of the spreadsheet to determine the data type in each column. If
>   the column does not contain a field value over 256 characters in the
>   first 8 rows, then it assumes the data type is text, which has a
>   character limit of 256. The following KB article has more information
>   on this issue: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281517

It's possible this issue is due to some blank rows in the worksheet, but I can't confirm.

Comment: Remove the brackets around InsertSql.

Comment: Doesn't change the outcome

Comment: Is the target workbook open or closed when you do the insert?

Comment: it's will always be closed

Comment: Where is dbpath coming from. Have you checked it has the right path?

Comment: its on the network and has worked in the past, so I know the path is correct. I just checked, and the insert works when the workbook is open.

Comment: Maybe not the cause of error, but you should change`con.Execute (InsertSQL)`to `con.Execute InsertSQL`as the parenthesis causes argument passed`ByVal`. Never use parenthesis that has a blank between the method and the leading  args parenthesis unless you want to pass args explicit as`ByVal`(means [no parenthesis on methods not assiged to a variable or using`Call-staemen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45747922/9439330)t (and that is obsolete)

Comment: Interesting remark given that you use the Access engine in this very query! Your company is actually only banning the MS Access software (GUI .EXE)! You can still create and use `.mdb` or `.accdb` database without the GUI installed!

Comment: Regarding your code, are you really hard-coding data in query or concatenating with variables or cell ranges. Try wrapping subroutine in proper error handling. I tested your code changing data elements and all works. Hence, I cannot reproduce your issue.

Comment: Maybe the network write permissions have changed?

Comment: I did check the network write permissions under the security setting, and it was read only for the "everyone" group. That may have been the cause, but time will tell.

Comment: It happened again. The code ran without error, but didn't insert any record. Now that I've opened to workbook that the code is inserting into, it works just fine. But eventually, this problem will happen again.